# Correcting an aggregation formula using regex in Google Sheets so that all instances are considered

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 cells in my spreadsheet. It looks like this:

```
D2 = {color: white, quantity: 23}, {color: black, quantity: 73}, {color: red, quantity: 10}
D3 = 106
```

D3 is being generated using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(D2, "quantity:", "♦"), "♦"), "}.*", "")))
```

In other words, all I want to do is aggregate the quantities.

It works, however, the quantity attribute must come at the very end of each "JSON" object. If I change D2 to this:

```
D2 = {color: white, quantity: 23, size: small}, {color: black, quantity: 73}, {color: red, quantity: 10}
```

Because I added the size attribute after the quantity, D3 now becomes 83. Therefore, I would like to do three things:

- Aggregate all instances of quantity wherever they occur.
- Make the matching case insensitive. So things like "`QUANTITY`" would also work.
- Spaces after "quantity:" should not be considered. So, something like `{quantity:100}, {quantity: 23}, {quantity:    120}` would also work.

How can I fix this? I tried removing the `"}.*"` of the regex, but that seemed to break the formula. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(
 SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(D28), "quantity:", "♦"), "♦"), ",.*|}.*", "")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Just curious, why does it read "uantity" in the formula above? I'm not familiar with google sheets.

Comment: @dwirony no particular reason. OP asked for case insensitivity so "uantity:" would solve "Quantity:" as well as "quantity:" cases. but it wouldn't solve for CAPS so LOWER() is needed for accounting for all possible states even "QuAnTITy:". the word "uantity:" does not exist so it's no harm to skip the "Q" anyway.